# Netlify build failed due to not finishing within time limit

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, netlify

I'm uploading my first project to `Netlify` and having some issues. I've been debugging and have fixed all of the issues I've encountered so far because they have error messages but I'm at a point now where my website is taking too long to upload and it's not a very large website to begin with so I have no idea what the problem could be.

```
12:13:18 AM: Netlify Build                                                 
12:13:18 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:13:18 AM: ​
12:13:18 AM: ❯ Version
12:13:18 AM:   @netlify/build 29.20.12
12:13:18 AM: ​
12:13:18 AM: ❯ Flags
12:13:18 AM:   baseRelDir: true
12:13:18 AM:   buildId: 64febdf8ece3553c9ec203d1
12:13:18 AM:   deployId: 64febdf8ece3553c9ec203d3
12:13:18 AM: ​
12:13:18 AM: ❯ Current directory
12:13:18 AM:   /opt/build/repo
12:13:18 AM: ​
12:13:18 AM: ❯ Config file
12:13:18 AM:   /opt/build/repo/netlify.toml
12:13:18 AM: ​
12:13:18 AM: ❯ Context
12:13:18 AM:   production
12:13:18 AM: ​
12:13:18 AM: build.command from netlify.toml                               
12:13:18 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:13:18 AM: ​
12:13:18 AM: $ npm run dev
12:13:18 AM: > 17@0.0.0 dev
12:13:18 AM: > concurrently --kill-others npm run start npm run scss
12:13:18 AM: [0]
12:13:18 AM: [0] > 17@0.0.0 start
12:13:18 AM: [0] > nodemon ./bin/www
12:13:18 AM: [0]
12:13:18 AM: [1]
12:13:18 AM: [1] > 17@0.0.0 scss
12:13:18 AM: [1] > sass --watch src/scss/main.scss public/stylesheets/style.css
12:13:18 AM: [1]
12:13:18 AM: [0] [nodemon] 3.0.1
12:13:18 AM: [0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
12:13:18 AM: [0] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
12:13:18 AM: [0] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
12:13:18 AM: [0] [nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
12:13:18 AM: [1] Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
12:13:18 AM: [1]
12:31:25 AM: Execution timed out after 18m10.001708592s
12:31:25 AM: Error running command: Command did not finish within the time limit
12:31:25 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
12:31:26 AM: Finished processing build request in 18m28.601s
```

The only thing I can think of is my folder tree and build settings might not be proper. I have a very basic folder structure.

```
├── bin
├── models
├── node_models
├── public
├── routes
├── src/scss
├── views
├── app.js
├── netlify.toml
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
```

And here is my build settings.

[image: build settings]

Here's also my `package.json` which lists my run commands.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "scss": "sass --watch src/scss/main.scss public/stylesheets/style.css",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run start\" \"npm run scss\""
  },
```

Comment: Those are development commands. You can't use `nodemon` and `sass --watch` to build for production.

Comment: this is not a [mre]. It's missing the dependencies properties of the package.json.

Answer (score 0):

@Andy was correct I was failing due to the build commands which is what I assumed. I was able to find a proper fix and now my site is live.

https://docs.netlify.com/integrations/frameworks/express/